# Why does creating an object of the Task class sometimes generate a "+"/"-" after the "-"/"+"

Tags: python

in self.task?

Here is the relevant part of the code to the question:

```
import random

buttons = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '-', '*', '/', '^', '√', ',']
class Task:
    def __init__(self, difficulty = 1):
        self.difficulty = difficulty
        self.task = ""
        b = ""
        for i in range(difficulty):
            print(f"difficulty: {difficulty}, i: {i}")
            if difficulty == 1:
                self.task = random.choice(buttons[1:8])
                self.target = self.task
            if difficulty == 2:
                self.task = random.choice(buttons[1:8]) + random.choice(buttons[:8]).symbol
                self.target = self.task
            if difficulty in range(3, 10):
                self.task = f"{random.choice(buttons[1:8]}"
                for i in range(difficulty):
                    if i == 1:
                        a = random.choice(buttons[:12])
                        b = a
                        self.task = self.task + a
                    elif i == difficulty - 1:
                        a = random.choice(buttons[:8])
                        b = a
                        self.task = self.task + a
                    elif b in "^+-*/,√":
                        a = random.choice(buttons[1:8])
                        b = a
                        self.task = self.task + a
                    else:
                        a = random.choice(buttons[:12])
                        b = a
                        self.task = self.task + a
the_task = Task(7)
print(the_task.task)
```

Ideally, the third condition (`elif b in "^+-*/,√"`) should prevent this from happening, but it still happens, even though it has never generated a self.task, which causes an error when eval() is used over it.

Briefly: sometimes when creating an object of the Task class, self.task like "256+-24706" is generated - the "+" operator is followed by the "-" operator. I don't want this to happen: i.e. I'm happy with "256+24706" or "256-24706" but not with "256+-24706".

Comment: Please assume we know nothing about what you're doing (because we really don't), and explain to us what this is trying to accomplish, and what exactly the problem is.

Comment: I've tried to explain everything in the clearest way possible. 
Okay, sometimes when creating an object of the Task class, self.task like "256+-24706" is generated - the "+" operator is followed by the "-" operator. I don't want this to happen: i.e. I'm happy with "256+24706" or "256-24706" but not with "256+-24706".
Is that clear?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with the actual definition of `buttons`.

Comment: Is that okay? (I edited)

Comment: During the first loop (i=0) you run into the `else` part and might get a "+" from `random.choice(buttons[:12])`. During the second loop (i=1) the first condition is fulfilled and you might get a "-" from `random.choice(buttons[:12])`.

Comment: You can interactively follow your program execution and even go back and forth to pinpoint such a condition here: https://pythontutor.com

Comment: A better naming would help other programmers to understand the program faster. `a` could be called `random_symbol` and `b` could be `last_symbol`. And all of this repeated codelines `b = a` and `self.task = self.task + a` could be written once after the loop.

Comment: I.e. is it enough just to change i == 1 to i == 0 in the first condition? Thanks, I didn't realize this problem was so easy to solve.
Maybe you can answer the question so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: Why do you have two `for i in range(difficulty)` loops? The outer loop never uses `i` for anything. It's also very confusing to use the same iteration variable with nested loops.